# Get all date, month, year between two dates C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, datetime

I'm beginner in C#, I have two DateTime, example:

```
startday=27/10/2014
enddate=15/02/2015
```

I want function with output is an array like:

```
 [
        [0=>2014
         1=>10
          2=>4( 4 is number of date in October)
        ]

         [0=>2014
          1=>11
          2=>30 (30 is number of day in November)
        ]
        ....
        [0=>2015
          1=>2
          2=>15(15 is number of day in February)
        ]
   ]
```

Please help me, Thank you

Comment: Your question is too broad and we can hardly help you if you don't try something on your own. If you are completely clueless, begin by looking at [the DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of this:

```
void Main()
{
    var start = new DateTime(2014, 10, 27);
    var end = new DateTime(2015, 02, 15);

    var daysPerMonth = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var currentMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, 1);
    while (true)
    {
        // Handle start and end in same month.
        if (start.ToString("MMyyyy") == currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy") && end.ToString("MMyyyy") == currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy"))
        {
            daysPerMonth.Add(currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy"), end.Day - start.Day);
            break;
        }

        // Handle last month. 
        if (currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy") == end.ToString("MMyyyy"))
        {
            daysPerMonth.Add(currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy"), DateTime.DaysInMonth(end.Year, end.Month) - end.Day);
            break;
        }

        // Handle first month.
        if (currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy") == start.ToString("MMyyyy"))
        {
            daysPerMonth.Add(currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy"), DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month) - start.Day);
        }
        // Handle full month.
        else
        {
            daysPerMonth.Add(currentMonth.ToString("MMyyyy"), DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentMonth.Year, currentMonth.Month));
        }
        currentMonth = currentMonth.AddMonths(1);
    }
    // daysPerMonth: 
    // {
    //    { "102014", 4 },
    //    { "112014", 30 },
    //    { "122014", 31 },
    //    { "012015", 31 },
    //    { "022015", 13 }
    // }
}
```